# Como pegar valores de um input e retornar dentro de um alert com Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho alguns inputs e gostaria de pegar todos esses valores e atributos de todos os inputs e retornar dentro de um `alert` com Javascript?

Queria pegar os resultados de forma geral, talvez usando um map, pois vai ter vários inputs em minha página e seria inviável resgatar todos os valores um por um.

Exemplo:

```
  <input class="exemplo" label="nome" value="maria">
  <input class="exemplo" label="sobrenome" value="silva"> 
  <input class="exemplo" label="idade" value="34">
```

**Resultado esperado no alerta:** 

nome: maria 
sobrenome: silva
idade: 34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu acabei resolvendo a questão usando o método `map`:

```js
var exemplo = document.querySelectorAll(".exemplo");

var values = [].map.call(exemplo, function (input) {
  var result =  input.getAttribute("label") + " : " + input.value + "\n";
  return result;
}).join('');

alert(values);
```

```html
<input class="exemplo" id="nome" label="nome" value="maria">
<input class="exemplo" id="sobrenome" label="sobrenome" value="silva"> 
<input class="exemplo" id="idade" label="idade" value="34">
```

Comment: Não precisa de `map`, um loop simples já resolve: https://jsfiddle.net/f5joz3cy/

Comment: O “problema” com o `map` é que faz duas varreduras, uma para o `map` em si e outra para o `join`. Com um `for` simples, faz-se somente uma. Outra alternativa que faz somente uma varredura é o `reduce`: https://jsfiddle.net/8bwq6ngj